# Wedge product of Endomorphism-Valued Forms

Tags: cohomology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, connections, characteristic-classes

To define characteristic classes in smooth vector bundles $E\longrightarrow M$ there is a more or less standard procedure: to choose a connection $\nabla$ and to derive the curvature $\Omega$, which is an $End(E)$-valued 2-form. In each chart $U_\alpha$, $\Omega$ may be described by a $r\times r$ matrix ($r$ rank of $E$) whose entries are 2-forms. The matrices change when the charts changes, but due to the tensoriality and the nature of $\Omega$, some quantities such as the trace or the determinant do not change for overlaping charts. (See, for instance, the first chapter of [Lecture Notes on Seiberg-Witten Invariants](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~moore/seibergwittenrev2edition.pdf))

Now to take full advantage of these invariant quantities (= to define Chern classes) one considers powers of the curvature matrix and their traces:

$$\Bigl(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega_\alpha\Bigr)^k\qquad\text{tr}\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega_\alpha\Bigr)^k\Bigr]$$

The procedure is ok, but if one studies it closer, one realizes that we are indeed defining some 'pseudo-wedge' map

$$\Omega^p(End(E))\times\Omega^q(End(E))\longrightarrow\Omega^{p+q}(End(E))$$

by simply taking the product of matrices whose entries are forms. But the question is

**Is there any way to define this pseudo-wedge product intrinsically, that is, by using only the classical wedge product $\Omega^p(M)\times\Omega^q(M)\longrightarrow\Omega^{p+q}(M)$ together with some linear algebra?** Perhaps there is already some book making an explicit definition; in this case it would be most helpful for me to have good references.

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

EDIT: See the discution below about the definition of Wikipedia and the relationship with the curvature of connections in vector bundles.

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form#Wedge_product help? The wedge product of two vector-valued forms is naturally a form taking values in the tensor product of the bundles. But you are working with End(E) which happens to be an algebra. // For a reference I think this may have been explained in Morita's Differential Forms book, but Google at least yields Greg Naber's _Topology, Geometry and Gauge fields: Foundations_ in section 5.11 around page 323.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, I think it is just the thing I needed. I will work on it more carefully, but I think the reference is the key point to have in mind. By the way, is there anything like the Hodge star for $End(E)$-valued forms?

Comment: Yes, just do it on the base. You should be able to find something in any exposition about Yang-Mills theories (on curved backgrounds) (there instead of End(E) your form takes value in a Lie algebra, but the principles are the same).

Comment: @WillieWong According to the definition in Wikipedia, it seems that if $\alpha\in\Omega^p$, $\beta\in\Omega^q$ and $g\in E_1$, $h\in E_2$, then $(\alpha\otimes g)\wedge(\beta\otimes h)=(\alpha\wedge\beta)g\otimes h$. Is that true? In this case, the formula $F_{A+a}=F_A+d_A a+a\wedge a$ for $A$ connection and $a$ $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form makes no sense!

Comment: I think the natural point here is not to view $End(E)$ as an associative algebra but as a Lie algebra (under the commutator of endomorphism). Hence you use the commutator to map $End(E)\otimes End(E)$ to $End(E)$, and there is a corresponding calculus for Lie algebra valued forms. This is consistent with the last comment of @Jjm in which $a\wedge a$ maps $(\xi,\eta)$ to $[a(\xi),a(\eta)]$. It also fits to the fact that the polynomials you use are invariant under conjugation, which infinitesimally means that they are invariant under the adjoint action in the Lie algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question exactly (this is a calculation in cohomology), but, having done this sort of calculation, recently I formalised it as follows.

- For sheaves $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules we have the cup product $$\smile\colon H^m(X,\mathscr{F})\otimes H^n(X,\mathscr{G})\to H^{m+n}(X,\mathscr{F}\otimes\mathscr{G})$$
- In Čech cohomology, this is give by the tensor product, i.e. $$(a\smile b)_{ijk}=(a)_{ij}\otimes(b)_{jk}$$
- Given the cocycle $$\omega_{ij}\in\check{\mathscr{C}}_\mathscr{U}^1\big(\mathcal{Hom}(E,E\otimes\Omega_X^1)\big)\cong\check{\mathscr{C}}_\mathscr{U}^1\big(\Omega_X^1\otimes\mathcal{End}(E)\big)$$ representing the Atiyah (i.e. Chern) class $\mathrm{at}_E$ of $E$, we can define $\mathrm{at}_E^2$ as follows:

  1. Take $(\mathrm{at}_E\otimes\mathrm{id}_{\Omega_X^1})\smile\mathrm{at}_E$ in $ H^2\big(X,\mathcal{Hom}(E\otimes\Omega_X^1,E\otimes\Omega_X^1\otimes\Omega_X^1)\otimes\mathcal{Hom}(E,E\otimes\Omega_X^1)\big)$
  2. Apply the composition map $H^m\big(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})\otimes\mathcal{Hom}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})\big)\to H^m\big(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{H})\big)$
  3. Apply the wedge product $\wedge\colon\Omega_X^i\otimes\Omega_X^j\to\Omega_X^{i+j}$ to obtain $$\mathrm{at}_E^2\in H^2\big(X,\mathcal{End}(E)\otimes\Omega_X^2\big).$$